# Php and Regular Expression performance

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to write a script to detect suffixes, words, and sections of written language. It will include a lot of string matching, so I want to write it based on regular expressions.

But I have a question about performance. For example, let's say we have 100+ different regular expressions and we want to match all of them simultaneously for an input text. How would that affect performance?

We have two options as I know, making an array of regular expressions and running them respectively with a loop. Another one is combining all the expressions with "|" and getting a huge regular expression string. Which one would be better by means of performance?

If none of these are logical, can you please suggest me another method to achieve that?

Comment: One huge regex is usually much much faster. Why, read [this excellent post on the very same topic, from the author of FastRoute](http://nikic.github.io/2014/02/18/Fast-request-routing-using-regular-expressions.html) - where he benchmarks and talks about the nitty gritty of regex.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you which is faster, but you can run both versions in this mini test suite (and tell us the results :D)

```
$startA = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    //First version
}
$endA = microtime(true);

unset ($all, $your, $variables);

$startB = microtime(true);
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    //Second version
}
$endB = microtime(true);

echo $endA-$startA."<br />";
echo $endB-$startB."<br />";
```